# SQL indexing Strings for query speed

Tags: mysql, performance

I want to query for strings as quickly as possible, where the searched-for string could have many thousands of matches in the database. There will also be other conditions to be met, and the returned result set will likely never be over 100 rows.

The option I came up with is to have two tables:

Table **items**

```
id | name_id
```

and
Table **names**

```
id | string
```

where ID on both tables is autoincrement.  and `names.string` is unique. `name_id` of course is not unique and would have an index.

And I will select from table `items` like:

```
SELECT names.string FROM items
JOIN names
ON items.name_id = names.id
WHERE names.string = 'abcdefg'
AND items.someColumn = items.someValue /*to further filter my results.*/
```

My intention is to save space and improve speed, of course.

Will this be faster than just using a simple `SELECT * from items WHERE name='abcdefg'`?

Are there any problems I should address, based on the information i've given?

Also, I'm not searching for substrings. Just the full match i.e. `names.string = 'abcefg'`

And feel free to ignore this question, since it's fairly broad, but are there other approaches that will be noticably faster (preferably without significant complexity increase)?

Comment: You should choose which database you are working with:  MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many good reasons for creating a reference table with string values.  Such normalization is generally a good idea.

However, it is not needed for performance reasons in your case.  If you have queries that are like:

```
SELECT items.*
FROM items
WHERE items.string = 'abcdefg' AND items.someColumn = <somevalue>;
```

Then either of the following two indexes are best for this query:

```
items(string, somecolumn)
items(somecolumn, string)
```

This is true in both MySQL and SQL Server.

You can index string columns and using the index will be efficient for most queries.  (There are issues if you start mixing collations, but let's put issues like that aside for this answer.)